# Rest assured response in ASC/DESC order

Tags: rest-assured, hamcrest

Is there any ways to validate the response in order?

```
"user": [
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "age": 21,             
            },
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "age": 22,
            },
            {
                "_id": "7",
                "age": 30,
            }
]
```

I can get specific id value with following

```
 .body("user[0].id", some validation)  result: 1
```

When I do something like this I will get all the ids

```
.body("user.id", some validation)  result: [1,2,7]
```

Need a validation to verify the result is in DESC/ASC order

```
.body("user.id", isDescOrder()/isAscOrder())
```

Comment: I am not very clear with your requirement, can you give a detailed explanation please ?

Comment: Ok, l want to check if the response body is in descending order or ascending order @WilfredClement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isInOrder(Iterable<? extends T> iterable, Comparator<T> comparator)` in [com.google.common.collect.Comparators](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#isInOrder-java.lang.Iterable-java.util.Comparator-).

```
List<String> user_IdList = given()
        .when()
        .get("api_url")
        .then()
        .extract()
        .jsonPath()
        .getList("user._id");

List<Integer> integerList = user_IdList
        .stream()
        .map(x-> Integer.parseInt(x))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean isInAscOrder = isInOrder(integerList, Ordering.natural());
```

Here `isInAscOrder` will be true. Because 1,2,7 are in ascending order.